# Sum multiple instances of the same fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have data that represents geographic coordinates.

```
{"latitude" : 32.7874, "longitude" : -96.7989, "ip" : "1.1.1.1", "load" : 10}
{"latitude" : 32.7874, "longitude" : -96.7989, "ip" : "2.2.2.2", "load" : 5}
```

Using db.collection.aggregate(), how would I achieve the result:

```
{"latitude" : 32.7874, "longitude" : -96.7989, "load" : 15}
```

Since both latitude and longitude have to be equal in order to sum, I am unsure how to use `$group`

I also know that `$project` will allow me to control which fields I get in the result, but I am unsure of how to use `$group` and `$sum` in conjunction with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include multiple fields in the `_id` definition of `$group` and then use a final `$project` stage to reshape the document:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: {latitude: '$latitude', longitude: '$longitude'},
    load: {$sum: '$load'}
  }},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0,
    latitude: '$_id.latitude',
    longitude: '$_id.longitude',
    load: 1
  }}
])
```

Result:

```js
{ 
    "load" : 15.0, 
    "latitude" : 32.7874, 
    "longitude" : -96.7989
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!